# Can I send SIGCONT to a running process?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I know that SIGCONT continues a process previously stopped by SIGSTOP. Can I use SIGCONT multiple times without a SIGSTOP ? i,e , below sequence is valid ?

```
SIGSTOP to process A : The process stops
SIGCONT to process A : Process resumes
SIGCONT to process A : Process already runs - this SIGCONT has no effect 
SIGCONT to process A : Process already runs - this SIGCONT has no effect 
...
SIGSTOP to process A : The process stops
SIGCONT to process A : Process resumes
```

Comment: The manual page says that SIGCONT means "continue if stopped, otherwise ignore", so yes.

Comment: why don't you try it and find out? stackoverflow is not a replacement for experimentation

Comment: @tbert: While I agree that experimentation is a very good learning tool, experimentation is not a replacement for learning how it is supposed to work. Think of undefined behavior!

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy okay, I'll amend my previous statement to also read "and RTFM". is your inner pedant happy now?

Comment: @tbert: My inner pedant thanks you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it. TLPI says:

> When sent to a stopped process, this signal causes the process to
>   resume (i.e., to be rescheduled to run at some later time). When
>   received by a process that is not currently stopped, **this signal is
>   ignored by default**. A process may catch this signal, so that it
>   carries out some action when it resumes.

APUE:

> Note that the default action for SIGCONT is to continue the process,
>   if it is stopped; **otherwise, the signal is ignored**.

Comment: Cool acronym use :)